# Reflection: Create instance of a class that inherit from another class located in separate assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection, c#-7.0

I created an empty web form application that run under `.Net Framework 4.7.2` and created a webform and a class named `MyClass`:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public string GetText()
        {
            return "Message of Web Form 1";
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string GetText()
        {
           return "Message from MyClass";
        }
    }
}
```

and I publish it using "Merge all assemblies in one assembly" option:

[image]

Then I want to get type and then create instance of `WebForm1` and `MyClass`.

I wrote this code in a **console application that run under** `.Net 5`:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Pub\bin\WebApplication1.dll");

Type tMyClass = asm.GetType("WebApplication1.MyClass");
Type t = asm.GetType("WebApplication1.WebForm1"); <----Error
```

After the code has run, `tMyClass` has the correct type:

[image]]

but when I try to get the type of `WebForm1`, I get an error:

[image]

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.Page' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

How can I get type of `WebForm1` and create an instance of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You load an assembly built in `.NET Framework` via reflection on `.NET Core`, but some of the classes in `System.Web` namespace are not supported in `.NET Core`. It load user code parts. And other parts may not work. In your case the requested class of the code compiled for `.NET Framework` is not part of `.NET Core`.
`System.Web` is for `Asp.Net` and in `.NET Core` the `System.Web` namespace exists and could technically be called but it won't work like you want.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the error is because `System.Web.UI.Page` does not exist in .NET 5. So you can't load the assembly for the purpose of executing the code within your console app.

However, you can still load the metadata of your class `WebApplication1.WebForm1` in a [reflection-only context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context) for the purpose of examining the type. The way you do it in .NET 5 is different than .NET Framework by using a [`MetadataLoadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/inspect-contents-using-metadataloadcontext) from this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext/).

```
var dllPath = @"C:\Pub\bin\WebApplication1.dll";

var paths = new List<string>();
paths.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(dllPath), "*.dll"));
paths.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "*.dll"));

using var context = new MetadataLoadContext(new PathAssemblyResolver(paths));
var asm = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllPath);
var yourType = asm.GetType("WebApplication1.WebForm1");
```

Also note, if you're trying to access the methods that are defined in a not loaded assembly, you will still get error:

```
yourType.GetMethods(); // Error
yourType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly); // OK
```